# Windows 10 setting is managed by administrator, but I am already an admin

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

[image]

I am already a admin, how this appears on my windows 10 PC?

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 are you running: Home, Pro, Education, Enterprise?

Comment: @AllenHoward windows 10 pro

Comment: And is this a machine owned by your employer?  It looks like there is a Group Policy in place turning off SmartScreen.

Comment: I have this , and its on my home PC , definately not a work PC. I'm baffled as to who it thinks the Administrator is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have antivirus that manage you system or the mentioned option had been manipulated from the group policy editor (if you have win 10 pro).
you can access group policy editor by typing "gpedit.msc" after pressing the win button. then go to computer administration ---> administrative templates ---> windows components---> windows defender smartscreen ---> explorer---> configure windows defender smartscreen (double click)---> Enable---> OK.